# Cases created from customer community are not firing email notification?

Tags: case, customer-community, email-alert

We have a customer community built on Napilli template. Our customer can create new cases by filling out the form(created using Global Actions) available on community.

When a case is created from the community, case assignment rules are firing but the email notification is not sent. But If I create a case with same details as an internal user the email notification is sent.

Do I need to enable any specific settings so that email notification works for cases created from community through global actions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do. See [Customize Support Settings](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_supportrules.htm&language=en_US). In Setup, you'll need to go to `Customize > Cases > Support Settings`. Click on edit and check the boxes labeled

- Case Creation Template (select a template if not already checked)
- Send Case Notifications from System Address (impacts a number of things, see docs)
- Enable Default Email Templates or the Default Handler for Email Action.

**Note:** You'll need to use the look-up dialogue to select the email handler class you'll be using to send your emails. You can also use that checkbox to select the merge fields in certain cases. Your community users would presumably need sharing access to that class and the templates if you want them to be able to generate those emails when cases are created from the community. I suspect that sharing permissions is the likely cause of your issue.

Comment: it was my mistake. We have a trigger running on Case Object and I had to add this line `dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;` to trigger email notifications. Thanks for your time!